# How to filter for strings with escape characters '\'

Tags: python, encoding, text-files

Here is some context to my problem. I am going through all of my files in a directory and encoding them. Approximately 80% of the files need to be processed as `UTF-8` and the remaining 20% need to be processed as `UTF-16'

My solution would be to first open files as `UTF-8`and the files that aren't compatible will return something like this (FYI this returns a string):

```
'A\x00M\x00L\x001\x00 \x00M\x00F\x00G\x00 \x00O\x00n\x00e\x00-\x00P\x00o\x00i\x00n\x00t\x00 \x00L\x00e\x00s\x00s\x00o\x00n\x00:\x00\n\x00\n\x00\n\x00\n\x00E\x00x\x00p\x00o\x00s\x00e\x00d\x00 \x00b\x00e\x00a\x00r\x00d\x00 \x00i\x00n\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00M\x00a\x00n\x00u\x00f\x00a\x00c\x00t\x00u\x00r\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00 \x00a\x00r\x00e\x00a\x00s\x00\n\x00\n\x00\n\x00\n\x00A\x00r\x00e\x00a\x00 \x00I\x00m\x00p\x00a\x00c\x00t\x00e\x00d\x00:\x00 \x00A\x00M\x00L\x00-\x001\x00 \x00F\x00o\x00r\x00m\x00u\x00l\x00a\x00t\x00i
```

And then, I would look through my data and find all of the files that resulted in the above format. This is where i'm having issues. I'm not able to search for the `\` and searching for `x00` doesn't work either.

Is this this best approach? How can I filter for files in the format above.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `'\x00' in my_string`?

Comment: Can you add the code which didn't work for you ?

Comment: There is actually no `\x00` in the file. The escape sequnces are used to show you data that would otherwise be unprintable. But you can use them like a string: `if '\x00' in your_string:`.

Comment: That file is UTF-16, not UTF-8. UTF-8 doesn't have all the extra NULs.